# Titanium Studio - Official tutorial issues and TSS syntax

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've started following the [Creating Your First Titanium Apps](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_Apps-section-37541502_CreatingYourFirstTitaniumApps-Introduction) tutorial from the Appcelerator documentation and I've run into some issues.

First, I think this is more an issue with the doc but I still want to confirm I'm not missing something. At the "Create a book detail view" step, it says to create a controller called **bookdetails**. However, in all subsequent steps, it refers to a the controller as **bookview**, for example:

```
var bookview = Alloy.createController("bookview", args).getView();
```

Entering everything exactly as it is written in the tutorial results in an application error saying something about an undefined controller "bookview", and naturally when changing it to match it all works fine, almost (see below).

Second, after "fixing" the above issue, clicking on a table row goes to a new page, but there is nothing on it, just a blank white page. I can't see any issues in the debugger and once again everything has been entered exactly as it appears in the tutorial, even just copied and pasted. Not sure what's going on here.

As far as I can tell with my limited experience, there doesn't seem to be anything in the bookview controller telling the view to display the extracted variables. The only line in bookview.js is

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
```

which is generated by Titanium and is untouched in the tutorial. I don't really understand what logic is happening here. Where is the variable `arguments` defined? Is it a global variable populated by the arguments from the second parameter in the `createController` function? Even if that is the case, how does the view know where and what to display? Shouldn't the view have output variables specified similar to the index view with `{title}`?

If I could figure out the API I might be able to tackle this myself, but I can't even find entries for functions like `open()`.

Finally, I'm a bit confused about the .tss syntax. Why are there commas separating some definitions and not others? Is that a way of grouping certain definitions? What is the purpose?

Also, does anyone know if I can download the tutorial source files from somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [Creating Your First Titanium App](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App) is BUGGY and LACKING right now (02/20/2014).

You can get a working example from [HERE](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/162330/titanium-creating-first-app-android-menu).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking multiple questions in one huge message. It's hard to address all of it and won't be useful for other users. Quick answers to some of them below but next time ask them separately.

**1. Arguments**

`var args = arguments[0] || {}` is common way in Alloy to retrieve parameters passed to controller using special JavaScript variable: [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). Link to MDN documentation should explain it. Code example:

**index.js**:

```
Alloy.createController("bookview", { title: "Design Patterns" });
```

**bookview.js**:

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
alert(args.title); // 'Design Patterns'
```

**2. TSS files**

TSS is a little crazy combination between JSON and CSS files. If you are not sure how to use commas in it just make sure to put it on every end of line.

**3. API Reference**

Here is [Alloy API reference](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy). Also [Titanium SDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium) has lots of code examples how to use different methods using plain Titanium and Alloy. If you've just started learning both Titanium and Alloy, it's good to go through all Titanium and Alloy lessons one by one: first learn how it works in Titanium and then try rewrite the whole code using Alloy framework.

Comment: It's all related to the tutorial, except the TSS part of course, so it made sense to keep it together. Making multiple questions for each little part would just be annoying.

Anyway, you're saying there is something missing in bookview.js and/or bookview.xml to tell the view what to display? In other words, the tutorial is missing steps?